# Extract data from a Postgres XML column using XPath

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, element

I have an XML data like this in my postgres table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Mydata>
   <LogNumber>10000</LogNumber>
   <LicenseNumber>XEU895</LicenseNumber>
   <LineCode>
      <V Idx="1">A</V>
      <V Idx="2">B</V>
      <V Idx="3">C</V>
      <V Idx="4">D</V>
   </LineCode>
   <OptionNo>
      <V Idx="1">999</V>
      <V Idx="2">27049</V>
      <V Idx="3">27049</V>
      <V Idx="4">999</V>
   </OptionNo>
</Mydata>
```

Using Xpath query I want to select the data like this.

```
LogNumber   LicenseNumber   LineCode    OptionNo
10000         XEU895            A           999
10000         XEU895            B           27049
10000         XEU895            C           27049
10000         XEU895            D           999
```

I have tried so many  XPath queries, but all are giving me only one value from the **LineCode** and **OptionNo** node. So any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`xpath()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) function returns an array of XML values. Use [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) to get elements of arrays returned by the function applied to nodes pointed by the first argument `xpath`:

```
with t(x) as ( 
values (
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Mydata>
       <LogNumber>10000</LogNumber>
       <LicenseNumber>XEU895</LicenseNumber>
       <LineCode>
          <V Idx="1">A</V>
          <V Idx="2">B</V>
          <V Idx="3">C</V>
          <V Idx="4">D</V>
       </LineCode>
       <OptionNo>
          <V Idx="1">999</V>
          <V Idx="2">27049</V>
          <V Idx="3">27049</V>
          <V Idx="4">999</V>
       </OptionNo>
    </Mydata>'::xml)
)

select 
    (xpath('./LogNumber/text()', x))[1] as "LogNumber",
    (xpath('./LicenseNumber/text()', x))[1] as "LicenseNumber",
    unnest(xpath('./LineCode/V/text()', x)) as "LineCode",
    unnest(xpath('./OptionNo/V/text()', x)) as "OptionNo"
from t

 LogNumber | LicenseNumber | LineCode | OptionNo 
-----------+---------------+----------+----------
 10000     | XEU895        | A        | 999
 10000     | XEU895        | B        | 27049
 10000     | XEU895        | C        | 27049
 10000     | XEU895        | D        | 999
(4 rows)
```

Play with it in [Db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bRAZuFN9hjrYC1QJXCzaeR/0)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have one more request. How can I list the Idx value of the OptionNo as a column with the above data ?

Comment: You can get an attribute value using `@`, e.g. `unnest(xpath('./LineCode/V/@Idx', x)) as "Idx"`

Comment: Note that `unnest()` expands array to table. Usually it is used in `FROM`, but here in `SELECT` two independent expandings lead to **zip two tables!** 1st row with 1st one, 2nd with 2nd, ... .