# Need to xml array attribute having the index and store it in postgresql table

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have a xml file which has array attributes and normal attribute. I need to store these array attributes and normal values into a postgresql table.

```
-<sample-test>
     <BookerNo>50105</BookerNo>
     <Type>
         <V Idx="1">A</V>
         <V Idx="2">B</V>
     </Type>
     <Value>
         <V Idx="1">50108</V>
         <V Idx="2">50158</V>
     </Value>
</sample-test>
-<sample-test>
     <BookerNo>50106</BookerNo>
     <Type>
         <V Idx="1">A</V>
         <V Idx="2">B</V>
         <V Idx="3">C</V>
     </Type>
     <Value>
         <V Idx="1">60108</V>
         <V Idx="2">60135</V>
         <V Idx="3">60158</V>
     </Value>
</sample-test>
```

Table name sample

```
col1    col2    col3   col4
1      50105     A     50108
2      50105     B     50158
3      50106     A     60108
4      50106     B     60135
5      50106     C     60158
```

Comment: See [Extract data from a Postgres XML column using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55847671/1995738)

Comment: Thanks Klin for the response. But it is not working in my situation since my file is xmlns file eg <sample-test xmlns="http://www.dmotorworks.com/sample-test">

Comment: You have to have the data in the database to use Postgres function `xpath()`. You can import the file to a temp table using [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command. Alternatively, you can parse the xml file with e.g. python script and one of its [xml parsers.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1912434/1995738)